# Would it be okay to say Allah is my best friend?

Tags: allah

Is it fine if we say Allah is enough for me as a best friend and I don't need anyone else when the Prophet Muhammad SAW also had friends?

Comment: _Wallah hu khair un Nasireen_

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I don't know the exact meaning but it is close to 'And Allah is the best of supporters/protectors'

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really say He the Almighty is your "best friend", rather to acknowledge that only He will always be there for you literally forever and knows what is best for you. He is your creator, and that is why you worship Him. i understand your intentions and where you are heading, but the wordings are wrong. You do need friends in this world, and you certainly need family, and it is a duty of a muslim to keep good ties with their neighbours, family and friends.

Comment: @Tashanna, actually the best brief point is like what you said "but the wordings are wrong". In fact, it is true that Allah is the best for everyone for eveything or needs but I reckon it is not comparable with humans to mentionig like that. God Bless You for pointing such rational matter in your nice answer.